# Why does coreutils's shuf scale so badly?

Tags: bash, shuffle, gnu-coreutils

I am using bash and shuf to shuffle a 400 million line file and it took about two hours when I operate on the file directly.

Since this is a little long for my taste and I have to repeat this shuffling I split the file into about 400 chucks of 1x10^6 lines and cat them together after shuffling.

Even with the split operation and the cat it takes just short of 10 minutes. Could anybody help me understand this bad scaling ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: The set of possible results is drastically reduced by splitting and shuffling just the chunks.

Comment: Also, `shuf` is a part of `coreutils`, not `bash`.

Comment: Probably a memory issue. Your two uses of shuf are not equivalent. In the first case the maximum distance in the output between two lines that were consecutive in the input is 400 millions. In the second it is only 1 million. I suspect that, in the first case, the complete input (or output) file could not fit in the available memory, while it could (or almost) in the second case. This led to much more I/O operations in the first case than in the second.

Comment: You cannot compare the two cases. When you split "one big file" into "many small files" you preclude the possibility to move lines from one small file to another so... the results are different. Also: sorting 400ML lines is more complex than sorting 4 ML rows 100 times (maybe using different cores).

Comment: Depending on your use case, the --head-count option might help you, see: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shuf.c#L540-L547